# No AMQP connection after upgrade RabbitMQ to 3.11.12

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, amqp

this night the plesk service has updated my Rabbitmq server with version 3.11.12-1 (old 3.11.11-1).
Now I have a problem with remote AMQP connection. the server rejected all connection attemps.

```
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0> closing AMQP connection <0.763.0> (192.168.245.66:40692 -> 192.168.245.66:5672):
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0> {handshake_error,opening,0,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>     {error,badarg,'connection.open',
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>         [{ets,lookup_element,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [ranch_server,{listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672}},2],
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [{error_info,#{cause => badkey,module => erl_stdlib_errors}}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {ranch_server,get_listener_sup,1,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [{file,"src/ranch_server.erl"},{line,122}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {ranch,info,1,[{file,"src/ranch.erl"},{line,434}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {rabbit_reader,is_over_node_connection_limit,1,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,1329}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {rabbit_reader,handle_method0,2,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,1225}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {rabbit_reader,handle_method0,3,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,1128}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {rabbit_reader,handle_input,3,
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>              [{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,1032}]},
2023-03-31 06:26:04.674063+02:00 [error] <0.763.0>          {rabbit_reader,recvloop,4,[{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,472}]}]}}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

How can I connect to the server again.

Comment: Also experiencing the some problem today after upgrading. Fixed by downgrading back to 3.11.11-1.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a bug in version **3.11.12-1**. Fixed by rolling back to **3.11.11-1**. For example on Debian:

```
apt remove rabbitmq-server
apt install rabbitmq-server=3.11.11-1
```

Comment: Downgrade was successful.

Comment: I had the same issue. Upgrading to 3.11.13 did help.